# How to add a new row and refresh my current page in Ag Grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using react and Ag Grid and I'm trying to add a new "row" in my remote grid with the focus and the edit, in that way:

```
const newRow = {
      COD_CON: 'new',
      COD_ABC: '000',
    }

gridApi.updateRowData({ add: newRow, addIndex: 1 })

gridApi.setFocusedCell(1, DEFAULT_KEY_COLUMN)
gridApi.startEditingCell({
  rowIndex: 1,
  colKey: DEFAULT_KEY_COLUMN,
})
```

but I receive the error:

```
ag-Grid: updateRowData() only works with InMemoryRowModel and InfiniteRowModel.
```

So I thought that a possible solution could be, adding the new empty row with a POST like this:

```
const newRow = {
  COD_CON: 'new',
  COD_ABC: '000',
}
const add = await fetch(`${my}/${url}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(newRow),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  credentials: 'include',
})
```

after the data is refreshed the new row is added at the end of my grid and I would like to reach that row with focus and the edit as I can do it in local with `gridApi.setFocusedCell(...)` and `gridApi.startEditingCell({...})`.
How can I do this?

Thanks

EDIT 1:
With @JulienD's comment I understood that my question was not clear and I changed it. Thanks

Comment: Assuming your POST updates your database, and that you get the table data from the database, you are asking how to insert a row in your database with a primary ID that is already used? Then you should use another column as an ordering criterion. Or do you only need to update the view and forget about the new row when you leave the page?

Comment: @JulienD you're right, my question wasn't clear and I changed it. By the way thanks for your help.